# Using Resharper Nunit tests start in a random temporary directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I am using visual studio 2015 professional
NUnit 3.2
resharper ultimate 10.0

My goal is the read the correct app.config.

This my code

```
 [Test]
        public void MakeEngineLoad()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Current directory: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            Debug.WriteLine(config.FilePath);
            var engineConfig = (EngineConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("engineConfig");
    }
```

This is the output

Current directory: C:\Users\u6035303\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14
    C:\Users\u6035303\AppData\Local\Temp\h1l4sot5.2xg\da7be2d2-7401-4975-b37c-40fc13a14c8d.config

I would like resharper to use the confile from the bin\debug dir.
I am even setting the option in resharper to start from the a specific dir.
Is this a bug with resharper or am i missing something?

Comment: That's the so called shadow copy, and the config should be exactly the same as your app.config if your project compiled successfully. If you don't want it to go that way, you can go to ReSharper settings to disable shadow copy.

Answer (score 0):

Nunit 3 by default runs tests in a temporary directory.

To reach the directory the .exe was built in, you need to use `TestContext.TestDirectory`. I'm unfamiliar with `ConfigurationManager`, but it looks like you can pass a path, so does the below work?

`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(TestContext.TestDirectory);`